# MYSQL Query Annualised Sales By Month Over Last Year

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to query the annualised sales by month over the last year.

I have this query to list the end of the month since last year;

```
SELECT
    e.date
FROM (
  SELECT LAST_DAY(NOW()) - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) MONTH as date
  FROM
  (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) a,
  (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) b,
  (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) c
) e
WHERE e.date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND LAST_DAY(NOW())
ORDER BY e.date DESC;
```

And I have the following query which can get the annualised sales figure for right now;

```
SELECT
    SUM(salesValue)
FROM turnover
WHERE date < NOW()
AND date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR);
```

I'm not sure how to plug them together however...

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . I would aggregate the data and use window functions.  Assuming you have data for each month:

```
select last_day(date) as month, sum(salesValue) as month_value,
       sum(sum(salesValue)) over (order by min(date) rows between 11 preceding and current row)
from turnover t
group by month;
```

If you might be missing months, then use `range`:

```
select last_day(date) as month, sum(salesValue) as month_value,
       sum(sum(salesValue)) over (order by last_day(date) range between between interval 11 month preceding and current row)
from turnover t
group by month;
```

EDIT:

If you want this over the original data, use the second form:

```
select t.*,
       sum(salesValue) over (order by date range between between interval 1 year preceding and current row)
from turnover t
group by month;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I'm unfamiliar with the over function. Currently Sequel Pro is returning a syntax error for this query. `SELECT VERSION()` returns "5.7.31-0ubuntu0.18.04.1" if that helps.

Comment: I upgraded to MYSQL 8 and this works, but I see it is a cumulative total based on the query results. So to get 1 year of correct values, the original query has to be over at least 2 years. Ideally, it would query from the raw data, but this will do for now!

Comment: @EdStephenson . . . Your data is an aggregation query so it looks like you want one row per month in the result set.  However, you can adapt the `range` window version for the original data.